# undefined reference to `__std_terminate'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I'm building a Win32 C++ library to be linked into other code using MSVC. The build is set up by CMake and I'm producing a .lib that was compiled with /MT run-time. BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is OFF.

When I link this library into an external C program (okay full-disclosure it's not actual C it's this BASIC dialect that emits C code but I digress) I get multiples of the following linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `__std_terminate'
undefined reference to `_Smtx_lock_exclusive'
undefined reference to `??3@YAXPAXI@Z'
undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
undefined reference to `__CxxFrameHandler3'
```

All this is leading me to believe that something wasn't actually statically linked when I built the library.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that .lib only contains your code. Then, when linking your C program, the .lib and the C runtime is linked, but the code is still missing symbols from the C++ runtime. As a solution, link your C program as C++ or explicitly pull in the C++ runtime.